# What is the standard existence theory of ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Sorry for my weak foundation. When I read Evans' book (picture below), I don't know what is the standard existence theory. Then I wiki it ,and I can't find. So, what I should read or google?Thanks.

> [image]

Comment: The theorems of Picard-Lindelöf and Peano are usually the standard existence proofs of solutions to ODE:s.

Comment: @lanse7pty You'll probably want to read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

Comment: There is a freely available book on ODE:s by G. Teschl, http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~gerald/ftp/book-ode/ode.pdf . Other than that, I suppose I have to search a bit myself for books.

Comment: I'm sorry to comment under an old question but this comment may be helpful to future readers. Here we don't know about the continuity of the coefficients. But they are using a different theorem. See Weideman-Spectral theory of ODOs-theorem $2.1$ or Coddington-Theory of ODEs-section $3.8$-problem $1$.